# Apocalyptic movie. Earth is dying and everyone is trying to survive or escape

Tags: story-identification, spaceship, apocalypse

The movie is somewhat from current era (2000+). It is most probably about the end of the world (or similar event) and people are trying to save themselves by different means - some by leaving to space, some underground.

The only thing that I remember is that the main characters are suggesting various means of rocket propulsion, among which is antimatter drive (or dark matter drive, or some similar as-of-now not possible). This antimatter drive is rejected as unsafe.

Then the main characters see on TV that some other company actually build a rocket with that kind of propulsion and sold tickets to some wealthy people who are now among the first leaving to the safety of space. But the rocket blows up on the launchpad because of the unsafe (antimatter) propulsion.

That is all I remember and the only thing I am sure of is that the propulsion was not used by the main characters (they only considered it). It was used by other company, who wanted to be first by any means. And that the rocket blew up during the launch. With all the other things (end of the world, propulsion type, etc.) I am about 60% sure.

Comment: Anything else that might help? Did you see it in a theatre? What language was it in (or what language was it originally in if it might have been dubbed)? Where was it set?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is [*Evacuate Earth*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evacuate_Earth) (2012), a *National Geographic* drama/documentary.  In the movie, a neutron star is on a collision course with Earth, and governments and private institutions implement plans to preserve something of our civilization in the face of increasing ecological devastation and the ultimate destruction of our planet.  The dramatization is intercut with real-world commentary from scientists.

A private group of wealthy contributors develops *Savior 1*, an escape vessel with an antimatter engine, for their group's own use.  The antimatter containment fails at launch, and *Savior 1* explodes on the launchpad (at 1:07:46 in this video), killing all aboard:

A later, successful launch of a different mission — this one using [nuclear pulse propulsion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_pulse_propulsion) — sends a generation ship to Barnard's Star.

Comment: Alright, that really did not come to my mind that it would be a documentary, that I was thinking about. :-) thank you very much